# PowerShell usage error with AWS CLI commands

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services

AWS CLI commands in PowerShell like ec2, s3api work just fine, but deploy commands always throw a usage error. Why is this?

**EDIT**

If you've worked with the AWS CLI, you probably are aware of what commands I am 
referenceing... But if you need example commands:

This works just fine in a PowerShell Script. So does aws s3api list-object, etc...

```
 aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-id $ec2_instance_id.Trim() --region us-east-1 --query "InstanceStatuses[].InstanceState[].Name"
```

This does not work:

```
aws deploy create-deployment --application-name MyWebApp --s3-location bucket=sthreebucketname,bundleType=zip,eTag=abac12345jkjdafdafdf,key=MyWebApp.zip --deployment-group-name DepGroup --deployment-config-name CodeDeployDefault.OneAtATime --description "MyApp Deployment"
```

I have set the user environment variable to my administrator. I have also set up PowerShell with my AWS credentials when I installed the Deploy Agent. So I should have no issue with access or permissions, but evidently it doesn't like the "deploy" suite of commands.

**EDIT 2**

Here is the error message. I know it says usage, but the same command works on the command prompt just fine.

```
aws : usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
At C:\scripts\deploy-to-instance.ps1:1 char:11
+ $result = aws deploy create-deployment --application-name MyWebApp --s3-location ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (usage: aws [opt....] [parameters]:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

To see help text, you can run:
  aws help
  aws <command> help
  aws <command> <subcommand> help
Unknown options: eTag=abac12345jkjdafdafdf, key=MyWebApp.zip, bundleType=zip
```

New-CDDeployment command from the AWSPowerShell tool does the same thing.
What other permissions need to be set then?

Comment: Please provide examples. For tips on asking a question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: See my edit above

Comment: I'd recommend using the AWS PowerShell module instead of calling the AWS CLI from PowerShell. Either way should work, but the AWS PowerShell module was specifically designed as a first-class PowerShell experience for AWS.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a permissions error at all. 
**The answer is:**
 
The syntax in PowerShell is different(more finicky) than what the command prompt expects. You need to have quotations and commas in the exact correct spot for it to work properly.

If you are using the --query option, make sure your query's have the EXACT syntax. It seems the command prompt cli can use a slightly different syntax without throwing errors.